# Preserving specific hidden directories while ignoring all others

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a git repository with a large number of hidden directories. One of the hidden directories contains configuration information which needs to be tracked by git, while all other hidden directories contain garbage and should be ignored by git.

File structure:

`.gitignore
.hidden_useful/
  file1
  file2
.hidden_garbage1/
  file3
.hidden_garbage2/
  file4`

I tried to ignore the garbage files with the following gitignore.

```
# Ignore everything
*
# But don't ignore .hidden_useful/
!.hidden_useful/
```

I also tried

```
!.hidden_useful/*
```

and

```
!.hidden_useful/**
```

Why should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works. I had forgotten to unignore the .gitignore itself.

```
# ignore all hidden files and directories
.*
# except the .gitignore
!.gitignore
# and the hidden_useful directory
!.hidden_useful/
```